# ASP NET MVC HttpDelete and Angular JS $http

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I thought by doing this:

```
$http.delete('/Category/Delete', { params: { categoryId: 30 } })
```

And having an action inside a controller called `Category`:

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<CustomResult> Delete(int categoryId)
{
    await this.categoryService.DeleteCategoryAsync(categoryId);

    return this.Json(true);
}
```

I would assume it would be called, but I get a `404` response.

I then turn the action result into a `[HttpPost]` and do this:

```
$http.delete('/Category/Delete', { categoryId: 30 })
```

But I get a `500` response. I'm not entirely sure what I am supposed to do here. When using the `HttpDelete` I have tried removing the delete action from the Angular URL. But that doesn't work.... I'm at a loss....

Comment: Did you try running the url from another rest console like fiddler, postman?

Comment: I've been using fiddler with no luck

Answer (score 0):

i think sending parameter as query string will work. Try the following code

```
$http.delete('../Category/Delete?categoryId='+30)
```

And use [HttpDelete] in action controller

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this.

First, keep the Web Api as is and change the angular:

```
$http.delete('/Category/Delete/' + categoryId)
```

Reason: WebApi has in the route table an entry for `/Category/Delete/{categoryId:int}` which would make our route need to have a `/` and the param value.

Second, keep angular the same and change the Web Api:

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<CustomResult> Delete([FromUri] int categoryId)
{
    await this.categoryService.DeleteCategoryAsync(categoryId);

    return this.Json(true);
}
```

I added the `[FromUri]` attribute to the argument, this means that Web Api will attempt to pull this argument from  the URI, which is looking like this `/Category/Delete?categoryId=30`